# Rest easy response status + body

Tags: httpresponse, resteasy

I have following method in my rest service:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    public String create( .... ) {.... return json;}
```

so I want to get a response with json in body and status code CREATED.

The problem is: I can't get a response the CREATED status.

The status code is allways OK, so it seems that "@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)" is just ignored...

Can somebody help me with it?

I'm using hibernate 4.1, spring 3.1 and resteasy 2.3

Comment: What's the full classname of `@ResponseStatus`?

Comment: it's org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to achieve this by annotating the method with `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus`.

You can return `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` from your method:

```
return Response
        .status(Response.Status.CREATED)
        .entity("ok")
        .build();
```

Or you can have `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse` injected, and set the status code directly.

There might be more ways of doing this, but I'm only aware of these two.

Working testcase:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher;
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockDispatcherFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PostProcessInterceptor;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ResponseTest {


    @Path("/")
    public static class Service {
        @Context HttpResponse response;

        @GET
        @Path("/1")
        public Response createdUsingResponse() throws NotFoundException {
            return Response
                    .status(Response.Status.CREATED)
                    .entity("ok")
                    .build();
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/2")
        public String created() throws NotFoundException {
            response.setStatus(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode());
            return "ok";
        }
    }

    public static class Interceptor implements PostProcessInterceptor {
        @Context HttpResponse response;

        @Override
        public void postProcess(ServerResponse response) {
            if(this.response.getStatus() != 0){
                response.setStatus(this.response.getStatus());
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new Service());
        dispatcher
            .getProviderFactory()
            .getServerPostProcessInterceptorRegistry()
            .register(new Interceptor());

        {
            MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/1");
            MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

            dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

            Assert.assertEquals(201, response.getStatus());
        }
        {
            MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/2");
            MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

            dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

            Assert.assertEquals(201, response.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```